# Cache images back to Azure CDN instead of to Disk

Tags: imageresizer

I am caching my images back to the disk with DiskCache, with a source of Azure Storage. I would like to use Azure CDN but once images get cached to disk, they are delivered from my web server, not the CDN. How do I make ImageResizer cache to my CDN instead of local disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLs that you publish should point to the CDN, *not* to the server. Disk caching is complementary, but the CDN should act as a proxy, not as a storage server.

[image: Like this]

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. So the CDN will cache the image for me after the first request, after it pulls the image from ImageResizer (which will be my origin server), and technically I shouldn't need DiskCache in conjunction with a CDN, but I could if I wanted to.

Comment: Correct. You might consider MemCache or SourceMemCache, depending on the size of your input data set and whether you have high-latency blob storage for the originals. DiskCache can still help quite a bit.